# Is there an equivalent to omit in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc, terraform0.12+

I'm working on my Terraform code, and I would like to use the same code whether or a variable is set or equal `""`.
But if I pass the variable with `""` in the `aws_vpc` module, there is an exception raised, saying a valid cidr is required.

If it were Ansible, I'd use the `| omit` filter which omit the parameter and don't pass it to the module if the variable is not set.

There is the code.

```
module "server_vpc" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"

  name = "servers_vpc"
  cidr = var.main_cidr
  secondary_cidr = [var.secondary_cidr]

  azs             = var.azs
  public_subnets  = local.public_subnets
  private_subnets = var.private_subnets

  enable_nat_gateway = true
  create_igw         = true
}
```

On this code, if the variable is equal to `""` (default), then `public_subnets` equals `[var.main_cidr]`, if the variable is set, `public_subnets` equals `[var.main_cidr, var.secondary_cidr]`.

But the part that didn't work like I'd like is the line with `secondary_cidr = [var.secondary_cidr]`.
When the variable contains a valid cidr, it works, but when the variable is not set and equals to the default `""`, Terraform raise an error from the aws vpc module explaining that a valid cidr is needed.

So I would like a way to create this vpc with the module, but not set the parameter `secondary_cidr` if the variable equals `""`.

I hope I was clear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws/latest) for this specific module `secondary_cidr` is not a required argument. In that case you don't have to provide an empty string. You either leave out `secondary_cidr` entirely or you assign `null` to it. Since `secondary_cidr` expects an array, most likely an empty array `[]` will work as well.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer.
You're right, it's optional, but it can't be `null`, I just tested it and it throws an error.  
  
But it can be `[]` you're right, I'll try with this.